# How to execute some arbitary Python code in InteractiveConsole before jumping into interact

Tags: python, compilation, interpreter, interactive

In a Python application I want to open a Python REPL via the [`InteractiveConsole`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/code.html#code.InteractiveConsole) class. But *before* I jump into the interactive Python prompt (via the `interact` method) I want to execute some commands given as strings. Here a Minimal example:

```
pre_commands = """for i in range(3):
    print(i*i)
for i in range(3):
    print(i*17)
"""

console = code.InteractiveConsole()


for l in pre_commands.splitlines():
    console.push(l)

console.interact(banner="", exitmsg="")
```

This always errors out with `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` on the 3rd line of `pre_commands`. It looks like push understand only *one* complete command (like

```
for i in range(3):
    print(i*i)
```

and not another command, despite the fact that `InteractiveConsole.push` has a mechanism for waiting until a command is complete.

How can I make this work with arbitrary lines of complex and simple commands in the string `pre_commands`?

Comment: Add a newline between the loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like interactive means Hit Enter/Return key after each block to execute it.

And Enter/Return key also means new line.
Your code works if I add new line after each print like below:

```
pre_commands = """for i in range(3):
    print(i*i)

for i in range(3):
    print(i*17)

"""
```

OR, 
Send each line with a \n, e.g. with the line console.push(l+'\n').

Comment: Thanks! That's it. Of course! Even more general: Send each line with a `\n`, e.g. with the line `console.push(l+'\n')`. Do you mind adding this to your answer?

Comment: Added your suggestion!!